# Populating a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, webforms

I want to fill a drop-down list each time with a link button(Edit) like this:
[image]

And I used this code to fill it:

```
sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT country FROM Authors  
                           WHERE AuthorID=@AuthorID 
                           AND AuthorUserName=@AuthorUserName", sqlconn);
sqlcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthorUserName", AuthorUserName);
sqlcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthorID", AuthorID);

dd_country.Text= ((string)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
```

But it fills the drop down list with a number!

If I change the code to the below something else happens:

```
dd_country.SelectedItem.Text= ((string)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
```

It caused changing the dropdownlist item to a selected item; for example it changed Canada to Burundi! In fact the items only changed temporarily and I then have two Canada items in the drop down list!

[image]

How can I fill the dropdownlist by edit button without these problems?

Comment: Onclick of linkbutton u want to fill dropdown list right?

Comment: No, on the LinkButton_Command of link button.

Comment: you want fill the dropdown in the gridview country column?

Comment: yes exactly what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the `Value` of the drop-down list to the number, and the `Text` to the country name.

Then you can do this to set it as selected -> `dropdownlist.SelectedValue=1` and it will select the country appropriately.

Avoid this problem using Data-Source like so:

[image]

A dialog box pops up that looks like this:

[image]

And you can follow on :-) from there